# Apple's iOS Subscription Services

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Now that Apple is allowing developers to create "subscription-based services," how do we actually implement them? Is it the same as in-app purchases, just recurring? Regardless of the feelings about the 30% cut for services which Apple doesn't actually supply, what are the technical hurdles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple has a [resources page](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/inapppurchase/subscriptions.html) up for it. In a nutshell as far as programming it is concerned, it directs developers to the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), which explains how to do it.